# For loop not accounting for all items?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I have a multi-selection imagepicker with the intention of allowing the user to select multiple assets, then upload each asset to the database. In the completion handler, I take all the selected assets and pass them to a custom function: `uploadImageAssets(assets: [PHAsset], projectRef: DocumentReference)`, where the upload begins.

In the function, I'm using a for-loop to upload each asset individually. While the assets are being uploaded correctly, **not all assets are being uploaded**. Lets say I've selected 5 assets... Only 4 will show up in the database, and they'll all be the same image, repeated. Any idea as to why this is happening? Here is my code below:

Image Picker Selection:

```
@IBAction func uploadProjectTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    
    let imagePicker = ImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.settings.selection.max = 10
    imagePicker.settings.theme.selectionStyle = .numbered
    imagePicker.settings.fetch.assets.supportedMediaTypes = [.image, .video]
    imagePicker.settings.selection.unselectOnReachingMax = false

    let start = Date()
    self.presentImagePicker(imagePicker, select: { (asset) in
        print("Selected: \(asset)")
    }, deselect: { (asset) in
        print("Deselected: \(asset)")
    }, cancel: { (assets) in
        print("Canceled with selections: \(assets)")
    }, finish: { (assets) in
        print("Finished with selections: \(assets)")
        self.getAssetThumbnail(assets: assets)
    }, completion: {
        let finish = Date()
        print(finish.timeIntervalSince(start))
    })
    
}
```

And, the function to add them to Firestore:

```
func uploadImageAsset(assets: [PHAsset], projectRef: DocumentReference) {
    let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let option = PHImageRequestOptions()
    option.isSynchronous = false
    option.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
    option.resizeMode = .exact
    option.version = .original
    option.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    let uniqueImageID = NSUUID().uuidString
    let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("project-images").child("\(uniqueImageID).jpeg")
    
    for asset in assets {
        let imageSize = CGSize(width: asset.pixelWidth, height: asset.pixelHeight)
        
        manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: imageSize, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: option) { (image, info) in
            let uploadData = image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.6)
            storageRef.putData(uploadData!, metadata: nil, completion: {
                (metadata, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    return
                } else {
                    storageRef.getMetadata(completion: { (metadata, err) in
                        if let error = err {
                            print(error)
                        } else {
                            storageRef.downloadURL(completion: { (url, err) in
                                if let error = err {
                                    print(error)
                                } else {
                                    self.imageAssetURLs.append((url?.absoluteString)!)
                                    guard let url = url?.absoluteString else { return }
                                    
                                    
                                    projectRef.updateData(["images": FieldValue.arrayUnion([url])], completion: { (err) in
                                        if err != nil {
                                            print(err)
                                        } else {
                                            self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                                        }
                                    })
                                    
                                    
                                }
                            })
                        }
                    })
                }
            })
            
        }
        
    }
}
```

I have a strong feeling that the error lies within this line:

```
self.imageAssetURLs.append((url?.absoluteString)!)
                                guard let url = url?.absoluteString else { return }
```

Comment: Debug and check, in assets all images is getting different?

Comment: @NikunjGangani yeah so they're all different assets for sure. I checked that already. it's just that the loop itself is uploading the same asset continously

Comment: Don't use **for** loop. Make recursion function, it's batter than **for**.

Comment: this is just a thought, but maybe in `func uploadImageAsset(...)` the 
   `let uniqueImageID =...` and `let storageRef = ...`
should be inside the loop just before `storageRef.putData(..)`

Comment: could you add a print("--> url: \\(url)") just before 
`self.imageAssetURLs.append((url?.absoluteString)!)`
and tell us what it prints. 
Also eventually you need to do the guard first, then the `self.imageAssetURLs.append(..)`

Comment: @workingdog moving the variables inside the loop was the correct answer! Thank you! want to post it as the answer so we can upvote it?

Comment: great, thanks. I've posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `func uploadImageAsset(...)` the

```
let uniqueImageID = NSUUID().uuidString
```

and

```
let storageRef = Storage.storage().reference().child("project-images").child("\(uniqueImageID).jpeg")
```

should be inside the loop just before

```
storageRef.putData(..)
```